# Symmetric powers and Frobenius

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a reduced affine scheme of characteristic $2$.
The *symmetric square* is $S^2 X := (X \times X)/\Sigma_2$. In studying the map $X^2 \to S^2 X$, one quickly observes the following. We have $X^2 = \Delta \coprod (X^2\setminus \Delta)$, where $\Delta \simeq X$ is the diagonal. This is a $\Sigma_2$-equivariant stratification and hence induces a stratification of the quotient $S^2 X = Z \coprod U$, where $Z$ is the image of $\Delta$ and $U$ is the image of $X^2 \setminus \Delta$. Moreover (and this is the main point for me), the map $X^2 \setminus \Delta \to U$ is étale, $Z \simeq X$ and the map $X \simeq \Delta \to Z \simeq X$ is the absolute Frobenius.

**My question is:** Does this generalize the higher symmetric powers and higher characteristics? Namely, if $X$ is a reduced affine scheme of characteristic $p>0$, is there a (natural) stratification of $X^n$ such that along the strata, the map $X^n \to S^n X$ can be described in terms of étale maps and Frobeniusse?

(I assume that, if true, this should not be particularly hard to establish. So I suppose this is mainly a reference request.)

Comment: $\coprod$ `\coprod` is meant as a large operator (like $\prod$ `\prod`), and so is both too large and badly spaced.  There appears to be no universally agreed notation for the infix version, but $\sqcup$ `\sqcup` and $\amalg$ `\amalg` are common choices.  Would you be amenable to replacing $\coprod$ by either of those?  (Also, is 'Frobeniusse' a typo, or an exotic plural of 'Frobenius'?)

Comment: The ramification divisor of the map $X^n\rightarrow S^nX$ is the union of the diagonals $\Delta _{ij}$ defined by $x_i=x_j$, it has degree 2 onto its image. If $p>2$ I don't see how it could fit into your picture.

Comment: @abx That’s only a divisor if $X$ is a curve, right?

Comment: For example if A has characteristic p then the image of the map $(A^{\otimes n})^{\Sigma_n} \to A$ is $A^p$, so the restriction to the diagonal is just the Frobenius again.